# Transactions with multiple datasources in Spring

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, transactions

I have 2 classes for working with JDBC and Sqlite. These classes use abstract class to extend:

```
package atm.implementations;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

public abstract class AbstractDAO {

    NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }
}
```

First class:

```
package atm.implementations;

import atm.dao.SQLiteDAO;
import atm.objects.Bank;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.MapSqlParameterSource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Isolation;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

@Component("bankDAO")
public class BankDAO extends AbstractDAO implements SQLiteDAO<Bank> {


@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)
    public void updateRecord(Bank object) {

        String sqlUpdate = "update bank set account_value = :value where id = :id";
        MapSqlParameterSource params = new MapSqlParameterSource();
        params.addValue("value", object.getAccountValue());
        params.addValue("id", object.getId());

        jdbcTemplate.update(sqlUpdate, params);
    }
}
```

And second:

```
package atm.implementations;

import atm.dao.TranDAO;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.MapSqlParameterSource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Isolation;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Component("transDAO")
public class TranDAOImpl extends AbstractDAO implements TranDAO {

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY, isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)
    public void insert(String desc) {

        String sqlInsert = "insert into transactions_list (description) values (:descr)";
        MapSqlParameterSource params = new MapSqlParameterSource();
        params.addValue("descr", desc);

        jdbcTemplate.update(sqlInsert, params);
    }
}
```

And here is context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="atm.*"/>
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/>


    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="username" value=""/>
        <property name="password" value=""/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlite:atm.db"/>
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.sqlite.JDBC"/>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true" transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <bean id="transactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>


</beans>
```

I need to make methods in two these classes Transactional, but Datasource is different in each instance of classes. Now i have error - No existing transaction found for transaction marked with propagation 'mandatory'.

First class updates database with new account parameters and second class just insert text in separate table about this transaction. If transaction failed, second class shouldn't insert any information.

I really don't want to join all code in one class, i'd like to keep it separated.

Is any method to use ONE SINGLE datasource for all classes??

Answer (score 0):

*TranDAOImpl#insert* is marked with MANDATORY-Transaction-Propagation. The meaning if this is, that the caller must have an active transaction. I suspect that you get the exception when calling this method?

So the caller itself should be annotated by "REQUIRED" or "REQUIRES_NEW". I don't think that your problem is related to using different Datasources. If your Spring-wiring is done correctly, the transaction-Manager should handle that in a safe way.